What does "that's a 30% from 2022" mean exactly?
In this podcast, I hear the following sentence:

New data from Oregon Heath Authority shows over 300 people died from overdose in Southwestern Oregon last year, that's a 30% from 2022."

What does "that's a 30% from 2022" mean exactly? Does it mean that 300 is equal to 30% of people who died from overdose in Southwestern Oregon in 2022?

"That's up 30%...."

I’m voting to close this question because it is based on a mishearing.

That's a 30% rise

The title says Southwestern Oregon saw 30% increase in overdose deaths last year.
The speech has elided  increase in

that's a 30% (increase) from 2022

So, 300 is not equal to 30% of the 2022
figure; it is 130% of the 2022 figure.
Edit
That person said

that's up 30% from 2022

Google sense 2 for up
has an example:

sales are up 22.8 per cent at $50.2 m


The word jump may have been skipped or not picked up by the mic. Or, there was a breath, not the word "a": that's (huh) 30% from 2022."

Thanks, @Yosef Baskin.  Yes, it's possible.  Could he have said up?

@SeowjoohengSingapore "Up" is what I'm hearing.

@SeowjoohengSingapore do you think the answer needs modification after the added comments, or it's still correct (so I can accept it)?

Thanks, @the-baby-is-you.  Hi, Kt Student, yes, I will edit it shortly.
